# Find rows where a column value appears at least twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
ID NAME  CASE_ID
1  John  33   
2  Harry 33
3  James 55
4  John  55
5  John  44
6  Harry 66
```

And I want to find the people who are in at least two cases:

```
ID NAME  CASE_ID
1  John  33   
4  John  55
5  John  44
6  Harry 66
2  Harry 33
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT name, case_id
FROM t
GROUP BY case_id
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1;
```

Comment: Do you mean greater than or at least 2? Because Harry was only in two cases.

Comment: sorry for my bad English   my meaning is at least 2

Comment: Why not provide a more representative example?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma in the `select` and that changes the meaning of the query:

```
select name, case_id
from t
group by case_id
having count(name) > 1;
```

Your original query renamed the `name` column to `case_id`, which wasn't your intention.

If you want the original data, then `join` the table back in:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select name, count(distinct case_id)
      from t
      group by name
      having count(distinct case_id) > 1
     ) nc
     on t.name = nc.name;
```

Comment: yup . that is the mistake when i typing the sql. but this result is not match what I want.

Comment: I want to show not only 1 record count name >1. I want to see all of them.

Comment: @chanjianyi . . . That is what the second query does.

Comment: I've tried .but both 2 sql result are same .

Comment: The result sets for the two queries are not the same.

Comment: I ran this in fiddle, and I think the discrepancy here is that this returns *cases* that have two or more *people*. If I understand, OP is looking for *people* with two or more *cases*

Comment: How does this answer work? If you select name, case_id but only group by case_id, won't the query blow up when executed? The name column would need included in the group by, or else you would have to use an aggregate on the name select?

Comment: @McAdam331 . . . That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are right. two queries results are different. So it seems the result from you and  McAdam331 are same now, right?

Comment: @chanjianyi . . . They look pretty much like the same query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and I have a question. how to do if my table t result is from multi tables maybe connecting by the poeple id or case_name?   do I need to create a temp table t, or I can get the result from one sql?

Comment: @chanjianyi . . . You should ask new questions as questions, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a subquery to accomplish this. I would start by writing a subquery that gets the names of the people who are in two or more different cases:

```
SELECT name
FROM myTable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(distinct case_id) >= 2;
```

You can join this with your original table on the condition that the name matches to get all of those people:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT name
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY name
  HAVING COUNT(distinct case_id) >= 2) t ON t.name = m.name;
```

This will give the results you want. They are unordered, but I assume you can add that if you need to.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c979b/3) example.